# Help illustrating step in proof about betweeness.

Tags: geometry

I am trying to do exercise 7.2 from Harthshorne's *Euclid and Beyond*. The question is as follows:

> Given a segment $\overline{AB}$, show that there do not exist points $C,D \in \overline{AB}$ such that $C * A * D$ [read $A$ between $C$ and $D$]. Hence show that the endpoints $A,B$ of the segment are uniquely determined by the segment.

So, I've been trying to be very careful, here was my attempt:

Suppose that $C * A * D$ then either:

1. $B * C * D$
2. $B * D *C$
3. $D * C * B$
4. $C * D * B$

If $B * C * D$ we get $C \in \overline{BD}$ so $C \in \overline{DB}$. If $\overline{DB} \supset \overline{AB}$ then $D \notin \overline{AB}$ contradiction. Otherwise, $D = A$ but then $C * A * A$ is not defined. (Also, disproves Case 3 by applying B1).

If $B * D * C$ we get $D \in \overline{BC}$ so $D \in \overline{CB}$. If $\overline{CB} \supset \overline{AB}$ then $C \notin \overline{AB}$ contradiction. Otherwise, $C = A$ but then $A * A * D$ is not defined. (Also disproves Case 4 by applying B1).

I feel like:

> If $\overline{DB} \supset \overline{AB}$ then $D \notin \overline{AB}$

is reasonable but unjustified using Hartshorne's axioms. Is there a way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, much easier way is to use the previous problem which gives you:

> $A * B * C$ and $B * C * D \implies A * B * D$ and $A * C * D$.

So: $C * A * D$ and $A * D * B \implies C * A * B$

But then $A * C * B$ (by assumption) and $C * A * B$ contradicts B3 which states:

> Given three distinct points on a line, one and only one of them is between the other two.